# Put United States on the top of countries list on sign up page in phpfox

Tags: php, mysql, xml, phpfox

I am having a hard time putting the united states on the top.I changed it in countries.xml.php :

```
   <countries>
<country iso="US" name="United States" />
    <country iso="AF" name="Afghanistan" />
    <country iso="AL" name="Albania" />
    <country iso="DZ" name="Algeria" />
</countries>
```

and in module/core/include/service/country/country.class.php 
I removed all the sql ordering like this :

```
            ->group('c.country_iso')
            ->order('')
            ->execute(($sIso == null ? 'getRows' : 'getRow'));
```

I cleared my cache and refresh  ctrl+f5 and Afghanistan is still on the top.
Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this through code file u can Set the value of country as a United States.
but in phpfox you can change it through database where the country table exist. I used phpfox in past, it took lot of time, but any way your solution is here.

Comment: it didn't work. I even deleted Afghanistan and its still there

Comment: worked never mind had to clear cache.yeah database + clear cache.also changed it in xml file and removed the ordering

Comment: gud fogsy, i really happy, at least my littke experience will work :p